# How to post statuses for users whos allow it for my application?

Tags: twitter

On my website, i want to allow for users, who is authorized with twitter, to post review on their own wall(page) in twitter, with my application.
I can do it for my page like this

```
$connection = new Twitter_TwitterOAuth(

$this->config->twitter->consumer_key,
$this->config->twitter->consumer_secret,
$this->config->twitter->token,
$this->config->twitter->token_secret

);

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $data['text'] . $data['name'] . "." . chr(13) . chr(10) . "More details " . $data['link'] .'?review='. $data['id']));
```

So what i need to do to post the same for another accounts ? i need to set account(where i want to post status with application) ID or i need to set other

```
$this->config->twitter->token,
$this->config->twitter->token_secret
```

with token and token_secret that i receive when user login with my application ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

for another account you should `sleep(//someseconds);` if you don't have a throttle in that library, then do the same for the other account. It looks like the account is yours, because in the code you posted I see so authorization from the user (callback). If my guess is right and you're using app authorization, you need to have authorized your own app with your other account, so ideally there should be no need to reset the tokens. If it doesn't work, try to reset them. If it still doesn't work, a trick is to have two applications (each account has an application, each account uses its own app to post). However, please bear in mind that a) Twitter counts the overall number of calls from your server and b) I'm not sure they like multiple accounts.

EDIT: if instead you need to post for users who have authorized your app and are currently online on your website, just store their tokens in a session (as Abraham Williams does in his library). In that case, you need to reset the variables to reflect the change of the tokens. Sample code, by Williams:

```
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$access_token_secret = $_SESSION["access_token_secret"];
/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token, 

$access_token_secret);
$message ="your message";
$parameters = (array('status' =>$message));
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);
twitteroauth_row('statuses/update', $status, $connection->http_code, $parameters);
if ($http_code = 200){
// echo "Done!";


 } else {
   // echo "Oops!";
    }
```

Comment: The logic that i want to do is
user login on website with my app -> user create review and set checkbox "share on twitter" => i post this in his page with my app.

Comment: ...well if instead you're trying to post with the access tokens of users, you need to a) make sure they want to post b) store their tokens first, when they authorize the app c) change the tokens for each user (so yes, you have to reset teh variables and authorize each post). Nevermind. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I was trying to do it like that(with user tokens from session)but it don't return nothing to me(don't post on user wall and no any errors or exceptions from twitter library side)